# Find any natural number $n>1$, such that $n^{100} < 2^n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find any natural number $n>1$, such that $n^{100} < 2^n $ prove that your n satifies this inequality

Have no clue on how to go on about this, could someone start me up on what to do thank you.

Comment: Your second expression is not an inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n=2^{10}$ would do, because $n^{100}=\left(2^{10}\right)^{100}=2^{1000}<2^{1024}=2^n$.

Come to think of it, even $n=1000$ is enough, since $1000^{100}<1024^{100}=\left(2^{10}\right)^{100}=2^{1000}$

As for how to find such number, there is no *elementary* function that would do it, so I used simple trial and error. Is 2 enough? Apparently no. Maybe 10? No, still too small. What about 100? No, $100^{100}>2^{100}$. Well, let's go further...

Comment: ahh crap, yeah cheers, i get it now LOL.

Comment: The inequality is $n^{100} < 2^n$. Finding a number that satisfies the inequality and proving that the number satisfies the inequality are different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for *any* $n$ so we can look for $n$ of the form $n=10^k$. Then
$$
n^{100}=10^{100k},\quad 2^n=2^{10\times 10^{k-1}}=(2^{10})^{10^{k-1}}>(10^3)^{10^{k-1}}=10^{3\times 10^{k-1}}.
$$
It remains then to find some $k$ such that $3\times 10^{k-1}>100k$. But this is easy; e.g., $k=4$ will do.